# How do I get rid of comma after last array item?

Tags: php, loops

I have this array loop:

```
 foreach ( $event_entrance as $event_entrance_s ) {
    _e($event_entrance_s,'holidayge');
    echo ', ';
 }
```

I'd like to ger rid of `comma` at the end of the last loop.
Any ideas? Seems simple, but it isn't for me :)

Comment: after your loop, strip the last character if it is a comma (which it might not be if it didn't enter the loop)

Comment: @MichaelRushton yes. it is required for my translation engine.

Comment: If you post your function code for `_e()`, I can add another suggestion to my answer that would implement the `implode` method preinheimer was talking about. It would work elegantly, although it would take more code than suggestions already provided, which work equally as well.

Comment: @jdstankosky: `_e()` is a WordPress function. The user probably won't want to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about...

```
$limit = count($event_entrance);

foreach ($event_entrance as $key => $event_entrance_s) {
    _e($event_entrance_s,'holidayge');
    if ($key < ($limit-1)) {
        echo ', ';
    }
}
```

As long as your keys are integers and sequential, this should work exactly as you intend. If you're using integers, but they are not in any particular order, putting this before your `foreach()` loop will fix that:

```
$event_entrance = array_values($event_entrance);
```

If you are using strings as keys instead of integers, try something like this:

```
$limit = count($event_entrance);
$i = 1;
foreach ($event_entrance as $event_entrance_s) {
    _e($event_entrance_s,'holidayge');
    if ($i < $limit) {
        echo ', ';
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: @itachi `implode` may fit on one line, yes, but the preparation for it would require you create a whole new array so you can add each string printed in his foreach loop into it before you call `implode`. How is this more efficient?

Comment: two ways. 1) It removes the need of `if` statement which checks everytime foreach runs. 2) it removes the mixing up of different logics. (speghetti code)

Answer (score 4):

```
$fn = function($v) { return _e($v,'holidayge'); };
$arr = array_map($fn, $event_entrance );
echo implode(',', $arr);
```

Comment: @jdstankosky: The first line declares a function that accepts an argument and returns the desired string. The 2nd line loops through the array, applying the function to every member and storing the result in array `$arr`. The last line implodes the new array on `,`. Have a look at the `array_map()` and `array_walk()` functions. They're really rather cool.

Comment: Yep, definitely voodoo. /me runs off to php.net

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

- use `implode` to put things together, it handles this edge case for you easily. Seriously, implode is great
- determine if you're on the last element (perhaps with a count, and by accessing the element key) and omit the comma if it's the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$event_entrance_count = count($event_entrance);

$loop_number = 1;

foreach ( $event_entrance as $event_entrance_s ) {
     _e($event_entrance_s,'holidayge');
     if(!$loop_number == $event_entrance_count) {
         echo ', ';
     }
     $loop_number++;
}
```